# Trying to work on R using Azure ML Studio Notebook and facing challenges with ODBC package

Tags: r, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to work on R notebook on ML Studio. Using regular python is easy and works as expected but with R i am facing challenges.

While trying to connect to MS SQL database using odbc() :

```
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "SQL Server",
                 Server = "server",
                 Database = "db",
                 UID = "user",
                 PWD = "password",
                 Port = 1433)



Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found
```

As suggested in some posts, i have also tried replacing  Driver = "SQL Server", with Driver = "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server". But i see similar error

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server' : file not found 
Traceback:
```

Please suggest a work around.

Comment: You have to [download and install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) the sql server driver. Close and reopen your R session and try again.

Comment: @stevec tried that still same error

Answer (score 0):

We can assign the **Driver** as the **version** of the **SQL server** and get the password using the API call.

```
library(odbc)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                  Driver = "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
                  Server = "your server IP address",
                  Database = "Database name",
                  UID = "User ID",
                  PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("password"),
                  Port = port_number_under_user)
```

In some cases, `Driver = "SQL Server”` will also work fine. If not functioning. Use the above code block.

Comment: `Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute `

Comment: Also, Since i am using Azure ML studio notebook (and not Rstudio) hence does `rstudioapi::askForPassword` work?

Comment: The current RStudio API is not attached to the existing ML Studio resource. There is another way to communicate with RStudio API. Check out my recent work on RStudio related things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73617139/rstudio-application-not-installed-in-azure-ml-compute/73630511#73630511