# RStudio application not installed in Azure ML compute

Tags: azure, rstudio, azure-machine-learning-service

When users were creating a new compute in AML environment by default RStudio application was created.
[RStudio application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKlMZ.png)

However, from month of July, by default RStudio application is not getting created. Only JupyterLab, Jupyter, VS Code, Terminal, Notebook applications installed not a RStudio.

[without RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcznA.png)

Is there any way to install RStudio application in azure ML compute instance?

Comment: Also, is there a way to add Rstudio after the compute instance has been created. In my organization, I can not create a compute instance myself, it has to be done by requesting the cloude infra structure team and they have created compute instances for me. I dread sending them these instructions to create another CI

Answer (score 1):

If you want to still use RStudio OpenSource you can do the following:

1. Follow the steps listed above to Add application when creating your compute instance.
2. Select Custom Application on the Application dropdown
3. Configure the Application name you would like to use.
4. Set up the application to run on Target port 8787 - the docker image for RStudio open source listed below needs to run on this Target port.
5. Set up the application to be accessed on Published port 8787 - you can configure the application to be accessed on a different Published port if you wish.
6. Point the Docker image to ghcr.io/azure/rocker-rstudio-ml-verse:latest.
7. Use Bind mounts to add access to the files in your default storage account:
8. Specify /home/azureuser/cloudfiles for Host path.
9. Specify /home/azureuser/cloudfiles for the Container path.
10. Select Add to add this mounting. Because the files are mounted, changes you make to them will be available in other compute instances and applications.
11. Select Create to set up RStudio as a custom application on your compute instance.

Answer (score 0):

The compute instances setup was changed. As RStudio workbench is professional edition, we need to get the license from RStudio and then use that workbench license in Compute Instance creation in Advanced settings.

[image]

By default, the instances will not have the RStudio. The procedure starts will Add Application under compute instances.

[image]

Select CPU or GPU as required and then choose the VM Size. By default, using the **Standard_DS12_v2** version of VM. Click on **Create**

[image]

Under **Advanced Settings** click on **Add Application.**

Go to RStudio and get the license for workbench.

[image]

[image]

Get the license from **RStudio Workbench**

[image]

Give the details required and target the port 8787 and published port will be **8787**.
Open **RStudio** which was downloaded with license.

1. Select **Custom Application** under **Applications**
2. Fill the details of the applications, like Application Name
3. Set the target port as **8787**
4. Set the publish port as **8787**
5. Set the Docker image as the target.
6. Under **/home/azureuser/cloudfiles** set the **Host path and Container path**
7. Click on **Create**

[image]

To access the **RStudio** services, go to the **left panel** and check with the compute instance which we created.

[image]

We can see the **rstudio-workbench** in the applications.

Comment: is there a way to add Rstudio after the compute instance has been created. In my organization, I can not create a compute instance myself, it has to be done by requesting the cloude infra structure team and they have created compute instances for me. I dread sending them these instructions to create another CI

Comment: To add R Studio we can use the mentioned procedure only. There is no alternative procedure.

Comment: I was able to add Rstudio using the same steps, except that compute was created separately by someone else. I could still add custom application in the same ways explained in this answer