# Can I use Spyder IDE with Azure Machine Learning?

Tags: azure, spyder, azure-machine-learning-service

I am learning to use Azure Machine Learning. it has its Notebooks (which are ok!) and also it allows me to use Jupyter Notebook and VSCode.
However I am wondering if there is a way to efficiently use Spyder with Azure Machine Learing.

eg. I was able to install R-Studio as a custom application using a docker image using steps provided here [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73617139/rstudio-application-not-installed-in-azure-ml-compute)

Comment: Are you referring to running the Spyder IDE on a compute instance?

Comment: Ideally Yes, or any other way e.g. running Spyder on my desktop but utilizing compute on Azure (similar to how vscode works).

Answer (score 0):

Spyder supports connecting to a [Remote Python kernel](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/ipythonconsole.html#connect-to-a-remote-kernel), it does, however require SSH.
[image]

You can enable SSH on your Compute Instance (see below), but **only when you set it up**. Also, many companies have policies against enabling SSH, so this might not work for you. If it doesn't, I can highly recommend VSCode.

[image]